# I want to create unique constraint based on check input start date should be greater than exits end date in db and need to apply same for jpa java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

```
create or replace function IsUnique (i_id smallint, i_clg_name character, i_pin_code character, i_start_time time) returns bigint as $$
begin
  if exists (
    select *
    from college_list as tt
    where tt.id = i_id and tt.clg_name = i_clg_name 
    and tt.pin_code = i_pin_code  and tt.end_time > i_start_time) then return 0
  else 
    then return 1 -- Unique
end if;
end
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

alter table college_list add constraint unique_key check (IsUnique(id ,clg_name ,pin_code ,start_time time) = 1)
go
```

Comment: This is not Postgres syntax. If you are trying to use `plpgsql` then you need to spend some time here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Comment: Your code looks like SQL Server, not Postgres. But if you are indeed using Postgres, then maybe an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) might be what you are looking for, not a trigger

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Could you please help on this

Comment: You don't want to do this as using a function is going to cause issues on upgrading. There is no dependency on the `CHECK` and the function so you will end up trying to fill the table and it failing because the  function does not exist yet. Do as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested and use an exclusion constraint. There is an example here [Range Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING). Look at the `CREATE TABLE room_reservation ...` example.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver could you please ping an example because i am not understanding range type example

Comment: It might be simpler for you to add `UNIQUE(id, clg_name, pin_code)` and `CHECK(end_time > start_time)` to the table.

Comment: but i want to check existing end time with newly inserting start time, will that work

Comment: Yes, but it means you can only have row per `(id, clg_name, pin_code)` combination.